# Retrieve and update data from SQL Server 2008 with AJAX/Jquery

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, scripting, get

I am presently working on a new development and I really need my project to have the silky feel it requires, So I thought of using Ajax or jQuery to retrieve data from SQL Server  2008. I am new to JSON and its functions.

Here is the html:

```
Enter Employee ID
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
<br />
<input type="button" id="BtnSearch" runat="server" value="Search" />
<div id="emp" style="display: none; margin-top: 40px">
    ID:<span id="txtId"></span><br />
    Title:<span id="txtTitle"></span><br />
    Name:<span id="txtName"></span><br />
    Department:<span id="txtDepartment"></span><br />
</div>
```

The Ajax goes as thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#MainContent_BtnSearch").click(function () {

        $("#emp").hide("slow");

        var empId = $("#MainContent_TxtEmpId").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "",
            data: "{'employeeId': '" + empId.toString() + "'}",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#txtId").html(data.d.ID);
                $("#txtName").html(data.d.FullName);
                $("#txtTitle").html(data.d.Title);
                $("#txtDepartment").html(data.d.Department);
                /// show employee details
                $("#emp").show("slow");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error calling the web service.");
            }
         });
     });
});
```

Is there any way to make my code better in such a way that it gets data from the database in  SQL Server 2008 and also be able to update that record and save database changes.

Comment: the URL in your ajax call is empty. There should be an url to a server side script that retrieves the data from the database.

Comment: Yeah I know... but its coming from the same page... e.g default.aspx. How do I get the initial method for the retrieving function?@Roger

Comment: have you tried using xml data?

Answer (score 0):

your URL in the ajax call can be something like: `Page.aspx/Method` so: `default.aspx/GetEmployeeById` and make it Post

```
public class Employee
{
    // properties: ID, FullName, Title, Department
}


[WebMethod]
public static Employee GetEmployeeById(string employeeId)
{
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  string connect = "your connection string";
  string query = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Id = @employeeId";

  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
    {
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
      {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", employeeId);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
          while (rdr.Read())
          {
            // fill your employee object
          }
        }
      }
    }
  return emp;
}
```

This is just an example, so your connectionstring and sql shouldn't really be in this method. Also make sure your `employeeid` parameter has a value.

Comment: Still cant get any data... Is it only thru web service you can retrieve your data?

Answer (score 0):

`
    $('#sqlLoadPerson').sqlRun();i m working in a mojoportal there i was connecting jquery with sql by just calling function sqlRun();
FOR example
    we can take a div

and we have to use this div id and using this call sql run

this will execute procedure and we will get result in front end